# AngularJS Changing a method into Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi and good day to everyone here,

I have a small function in AngularJS which is used to provide different maximum length to a textfield base on user's input, the codes are as following

```
$scope.limit = '0';
$scope.textLengthFilter = function() {
        var x = $scope.han.substr(0, 1);
        //console.log("Show: " + x);
        var numberRegex = /[0-9]/;
        var alphaRegex = /^[AHK]/;

        if (numberRegex.test(x)) {
            $scope.limit = '7';
            console.log('number' + $scope.limit);

        } else if (alphaRegex.test(x)) {
            $scope.limit = '8';
            console.log('Alphanumber' + $scope.limit);
        }
    };
```

and my html is the following

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="han" ng-change="textLengthFilter()" maxlength={{limit}}>{{han}}</input>
```

This is working good but i wan to move further too make it a custom Directive but i am still not understand on how to starts to write a custom directive by my own.

Anyone here can guide me on how to change my function into a custom directive??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code:

```
app.directive('myLimit', function(){
      return {
        scope: {
          myLimit: '=' // this is the variable that you pass in
        },
        restrict: 'A', // this says you want to use this directive as an attribute
        link: function(scope, element){
          var defaultLimit = 7; // this can also be passed in as a variable if you like
          element.attr('maxlength', defaultLimit); // set the maxlength attribute
          angular.element(element).on('keyup', textLengthFilter); // bind the filter function

          function textLengthFilter() {
              var x = scope.myLimit.substr(0, 1);
              var numberRegex = /[0-9]/;
              var alphaRegex = /^[AHK]/;

              // updated the maxlength attribute based on condition
              if (numberRegex.test(x)) {
                  element.attr('maxlength', defaultLimit);
              } else if (alphaRegex.test(x)) {
                  element.attr('maxlength', 8);
              }
          }
        }
      };
  });
```

And then in your template you do:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="han" my-limit="han" />
```

The code can be more concise and simplified, it is explicit just for demo purposes. Ask if there' something I can explain.

Comment: Btw, you should consider accepting one of the comments as an answer.

Comment: Since i'm still new member and can't vote yet.... I will take yours into my own work and tweak a little to fit in mine.... Thanks alot for it....

Comment: I didn't mean voting. Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted".
By doing so you're letting everyone know that the question doesn't need any further answers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be looked like this:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {    
    return {
            restrict: 'A',            
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {                
                var limit = 0;                

                element.bind('change', function(e) {   

                    var x = element.val().substr(0, 1);

                    var numberRegex = new RegExp(/[0-9]/);
                    var alphaRegex = new RegExp(/^[AHK]/);

                    if (numberRegex.test(x)) {
                        limit = 7;
                        console.log('number ' + limit);            
                    } else if (alphaRegex.test(x)) {
                        limit = 8;
                        console.log('Alphanumber ' + limit);
                    }

                    element.attr('maxlength', limit);
                });
            }
        };
});
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" my-directive></input>
```

PS. Seems your regexp has been broken.